# Oracle Client Tuning?

Tags: oracleclient

Is there a way to tune the Oracle client (InstantClient or the normal one)?

We have a software that runs on multiple DMBS (MySQL, PGSQL and MS SQL Server) I'm wondering why the Oracle version of the product consume more resources than the other ones.

UPDATE: I'm using the C++ API (OCI).

Comment: What resource is it using?  What client arr ypu using C++ Java, .Net or other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well depending on the version of oracle and client you can tune your connection to oracle, largely through using the tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora.  you can change all sorts of things like buffer sizes, etc.  This is an example of one: [SDU & MTU sizes](http://www.dba-oracle.com/tips_oracle_tnsnames_ora_file.htm).  As for resources, the DLL from the oracle client is HUGE and will consume more memory/disk space then the other ones.  I know the OCI.dll we use is 100+ mb dll.  Other then that I would ask you to be more specific as what resources you would like to tune?